# Force ThreadPool to start the thread sooner

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem for creating a thread on Windows CE (I use .NET Framework 3.5). Sometimes the thread waits for something and starts too late. In the QueueUserWorkItem documentation it says that the delegate will be executed "when a thread pool thread becomes available".

Is there a way to force the ThreadPool to execute my delegate immediately? Would Thread.Start() be a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: I want to know this too

Comment: If you need the task to execute immediately then you are better of using a thread.

Comment: It doesn't give more guarantee about when it will be executed.

Comment: @C4stor How so? Using `Thread` creates a new thread on the spot, and doesn't wait for a ThreadPool thread to become available.

Comment: @C4stor If you're concerned about when a thread should be scheduled to run by the operating system then C# is probably not the right tool for that use case.

Comment: My guess is either you don't really need this, and waiting the short amount of time for a thread pool thread to be freed is fine, even if you don't think it is, or your program is abusing the thread pool somewhere and completely flooding it with more than it can handle, filling it with tons of long running operations, or some other use it isn't designed to handle; in such cases the proper solution is to address those issues and use the thread pool properly elsewhere in your application.

Comment: If you can't wait, why are you queuing?  Maybe you could post some more details about why you are using the ThreadPool?

Comment: @Rotem : It creates a new thread, and then the thread waits to be executed. A computer can't run any number of threads at the same time, so if the thread pool is already overloaded, most probably adding even more threads won't help.

Comment: @C4stor Threads you manually create are not part of the thread pool and do not depend on availability of threads in the pool, see Tudors answer.

Comment: @Rotem That's true, but if the CPU is spending it's time letting thread pool threads run then it could take some time before it's able to schedule a new thread to run.  It'll could potentially be quicker than using the thread pool, but it's still not instantaneous, and if the thread pool *isn't* overloaded then the overhead of creating a new thread is very likely to be much worse than using the thread pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `QueueUserWorkItem` doesn't create a thread, it merely places a "task" in the ThreadPool's queue for the workers to pick up and execute. In case of saturation (more tasks than available threads), there is no guarantee of when a worker will become available to execute the task. If you want immediate execution use an instance of `Thread` instead. The only way to improve your odds with the ThreadPool is to increase the number of workers.

**Edit**: Just to be clear, if thread pool threads are indeed free, they will pick up work and execute it usually faster than starting a fresh thread.

Comment: Note that even with the direct use of the `Thread` class you can't be sure that your thread will be scheduled to run *immediately*.

Comment: @Servy: Indeed, it won't. But that has to do with the OS scheduler. The ThreadPool doesn't guarantee it by the very way it's implemented.

Comment: My point was that *neither* guarantee immediate execution.  Note that in many situations, if there's already a free thread pool thread, it will actually be quicker than creating a new thread.  Creating a thread takes time; allowing an already created thread pool thread to start doing work takes much less time.  The thread pool will have a longer worst case time, but a shorter average case time; it's all about which is more important for you.

Answer (score 1):

A ThreadPool have a limited size. So you can't lunch as many thread as you want in the same time. If all the threads are busy then you have to wait for one to become available.

Check the number of thread you want to lunch and compare it to the Threadpool size -> `GetMaxThreads()`

Then if you want more thread just resize the pool with `SetMaxThreads(int)`

Answer (score 1):

If you start a lot of threads from a pool you can get situation when there is no a free thread and your request is queued, that's why sometimes it starts to late. Try to increase a max number of worker threads in the pool. Use `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads` and `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` to configure the pool.

Comment: If you're at the point where you have *that* many threads then odds are your CPU wouldn't be able to keep up by adding more.  It'll just spend more and more time doing context switches and throughput will go *down*, not up.  If there really is *that* much work to be done then having some waiting time is simply unavoidable.  The better fix is to get more/better hardware.

Comment: @Servy, not if the other tasks queued to the threadpool are blocked, eg. on network or other I/O calls.

Comment: @MartinJames Then it means you're not properly using your thread pool.  You shouldn't be using it to have lots of threads sitting there blocking waiting on IO, and if at all possible you should be refactoring your program to not do that, rather than just increasing the limit or creating your own threads, as that's just sweeping the problem under the run instead of fixing it.

Comment: @Servy I completely agree with you, my answer is wrong. Controlling a size of the pool is bad idea.