# Run a new thread immediately

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a WPF app with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1 and SQL Server 2012 SP3 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 Code First.

I need to run a thread immediately but now it doesn't run immediately with this code:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    RequestNewCodes();
});
private void RequestNewCodes()
{
    log.DebugFormat("Task thread ID: {0} - {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));

    try
    {
        trazabilidad.InsertNewCodesWeb(1, codesManagerURL);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(string.Format("InsertNewCodesWeb nivel 1: {0}", ex.ToString()));
    }
}
```

`Task.Run` documentation said:

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task
>   object that represents that work.

But I don't want to queue it.

How can I run a thread immediately without using ThreadPool?

Immediately means not to push the task in a pool and wait its turn.

I'm not reusing connections. Every time I connect to database I create a new DbContext and destroy it at the end.

This is not a duplicate question. I have tested all the answer for that question and it doesn't work for me. I have found how to solve this problem and I want to share with you but I can't because this question is closed.

Comment: By using a thread. Tasks are not threads. `new Thread().Start()`.

Comment: Likely, it does run immediately. If not, your thread pool is overloaded. How did you determine how long it takes until this code runs?

Comment: @usr Because that code is a method that it's called 21 times. That code inserts data into database with a date and I've checked that the data it's inserted 21 times (there are 21 rows in database )after all other processes have ended.

Comment: Define "immediately". As soon as you hand off work to another task/thread, you have no means of knowing how and when that work will complete - unless you use explicit synchronization primitives, and the more guarantees you seek over synchronization, the more likely it is that you should have just completed the work on your original thread and not shifted the work elsewhere anyway.

Comment: Then you have a bug. It's not a ThreadPool problem. Why do you use a task anyway instead of asynchronous ADO.NET operations? Are you trying to reuse the same connection perhaps? Taking locks? Is there blocking in the database? Please post the data access code

Comment: If the entries get stored *after* other processes, it means that all processes end up locking/waiting on the same resource, possibly a singleton connection. Did you try debugging your application? Did you check the `Parallel Stacks` debug window?

Comment: A ThreadPool can have *thousands* of threads and adjusts its size as needed. You can also specify min/max limits to ensure there are always threads available for use. It's a way to *increase* responsiveness over raw threads

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework to connect to database and immediately means not to push the task in a pool and wait its turn.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994896/task-run-takes-much-time-to-start-the-task and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944030/force-threadpool-to-start-the-thread-sooner, for example

Comment: If you want to do something 'immediately', don't use a Task, don't spawn a Thread, just *execute the code*!?

Comment: @AakashM I can't do that because it will slow down the main code.

Comment: The moment you start doing processing on more than one thread, you lose control of *exactly* when each part executes. That's pretty much multithreading 101...

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and don't telling why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just instantiate a Thread

```
Thread task = new Thread(()=>
{
     try
     {
         ConnectToCodeManager();

         string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnection"].ConnectionString;

         SQLTrazabilidadStorage storage = new SQLTrazabilidadStorage(connectionString);

         storage.SendAggregation(parentCode, codesManagerURL);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         log.Error(string.Format("SendAggregation to TrzCodesManagerWS: {0}", ex.ToString()));
     }
});
task.Start();
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ThreadPool. Starting a raw thread isn't going to fix concurrency problems in the data access code

Comment: true, but it is a simple way to get more control over how and when it goes.
For now it is not possible to say if it is a concurrency problem he is describing or VansFannel just wants to control the action.

Comment: No, you get even more delay - you have to *create* the thread which takes a lot of time. The ThreadPool contains ready-to-use threads which can be used immediatelly. A ThreadPool can contain thousands of threads, so if you really want immediate response, just set a minimum limit.

Comment: There isn't any block in Database's tables. Maybe there isn't any connection available in database.

Comment: Concurrency is only solved in the objects/functions which he uses to collect the data not in this piece of code. So I thought it would be prudent to show a possible way to have more control for **when** the action is taking place... A threadpool doesn't give the same control as a own Thread.

Comment: I've been testing it and I've found that sometimes a `Task.Run` takes two minutes to start. I know that because I have a log that it executes the first one. I don't think there is a problem with my algorithm, maybe there are a lot of threads trying to run. In logs file I've found that threads running have a long ID 441.

Comment: I'm not getting more delay when I start the new thread. When I do that it starting faster than Task.Run. I have stressed my software and a new thread can start every 0.5s. Now I'm running it since fourteen hours ago and it is starting a new thread every 7s without any delay.